# WMI - query multiple informations

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I want to get multiple informations from a few server in my environment.

This code is working, but is this code a good way to get the informations?

Is it ok to call "new ManagementObjectSearcher" at every request?

```
ManagementObjectSearcher cpuUsage = new ManagementObjectSearcher
      ("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\CIMV2", 
      "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in cpuUsage.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("LoadPercentage: {0}", queryObj["LoadPercentage"]);
}

ManagementObjectSearcher totalRAM = new ManagementObjectSearcher
       ("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\CIMV2", 
       "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in totalRAM.Get())
{
  Console.WriteLine("TotalPhysicalMemory: {0}", queryObj["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);
}

ManagementObjectSearcher freeRAM = new ManagementObjectSearcher
  ("\\\\" + strComputer + "\\root\\CIMV2", 
      "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in freeRAM.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("AvailableMBytes: {0}", queryObj["AvailableMBytes"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar. My application is longer running so I keep one `ManagementScope` per machine and one `ManagementObjectSearcher` per query per machine. I only dispose of these objects when if I get any error during a query.

Answer (score 1):

You should reuse the `ManagementObjectSearcher` as it connects to the server each time and that will be an overhead.

For a little more efficiency, instead of using `SELECT * FROM` in your wql you can specify what properties you want, ie

```
SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_ComputerSystem
```